# How can we add dynamic url into security.yaml in symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, security, routes, symfony4

Suppose, we have a route like:

```
drive_student_list:
path: /download-pdf/{drive}/{driveId}/{type}
controller: SomeController::someFunction
requirements: 
drive: campus|walkin
driveId: '\d+'
type: applied|attended|qualified
```

which generates urls like:

> /download-pdf/campus/1/applied

or,

> /download-pdf/walkin/3/qualified

**How can I add this route to my security.yaml so that only admin can access this route ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add such url in security.yaml as follow:

```
 - { path: '^/download-pdf/', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```